# NullReferenceException at Response.Write

Tags: c#, asp.net, nullreferenceexception, response.redirect

```
protected void Btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BLL.Bll Bll = new BLL.Bll();
    String Result = Bll.Login(TBNomelog.Text, TBPasslog.Text);
    String UserID = Bll.UserID(TBNomelog.Text);
    Session ["IDutil"] = UserID;
    Response.Write(Session["IDultil"].ToString());

    if (Result.Equals("True"))
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 2;
    }
    else
    {
        MultiView1.ActiveViewIndex = 1;
    }
}
```

}

I'm getting "NullReferenceException was unhadled by user code" when i execute Response.Write
Any sugestions why this may be happening?

Comment: Debug through. What is the value of `UserID` when that line is called?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to read from session object with another key than you are writing in row above ("IDutil" is not equal to "IDultil)

```
Session ["IDutil"] = UserID;
Response.Write(Session["IDultil"].ToString()); // Session["IDultil"] will be null
```

Comment: didn't noticed that l thank you and well sorry for posting this thing